Compute FFT after reading accelerometer data
I'd like to detect abnormal vibrations on a motor I have.
I'm using the following devices:

Raspberry PI 5
Adafruit accelerometer ISM330DHCX

I've successfully managed to read the sensor at a specific rate (2000Hz) and I'm using it's absolute value (although it's not changing that much):
def read_sensor():
    global data
    target_duration = 1 / SAMPLE_RATE

    # Connect to sensor
    ...

    while True:
        loop_start_time = time.perf_counter()

        x, y, z = accelerometer.acceleration
        acceleration = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
        data = np.roll(data, -1)
        data[-1] = acceleration

        # Try to get exactly SAMPLE_RATE per second
        loop_duration = time.perf_counter() - loop_start_time
        sleep_time = max(0, target_duration - loop_duration)
        end_time = time.perf_counter() + sleep_time
        while time.perf_counter() < end_time: pass

Then, I use numpy.fft to compute the FFT on the above data and save it to a CSV file:
n = len(data)
fft = abs(np.fft.fft(data * np.blackman(n)))[:n//2]
amplitudes = np.abs(fft) / n

# Identify max frequencies
max_amplitude = np.max(amplitudes)
max_index = np.argmax(amplitudes)
frequencies = np.fft.fftfreq(n, d=1/n)[:n//2]

# Generate summary
result = {
    'mean': round(data.mean(), 4),
    'std': round(data.std(), 4),
    'max': round(data.max(), 4),
    'min': round(data.min(), 4),
    'range': round(data.max() - data.min(), 4),
    'fft_mean': round(np.mean(fft), 4),
    'fft_std': round(np.std(fft), 4),
    'max_freq': round(frequencies[max_index], 4),
    'max_amp': round(max_amplitude, 4),
    'speed': duty_cycle
}

It produces lines like these ones:
mean,std,max,min,range,fft_mean,fft_std,max_freq,max_amp,speed
9.9587,0.1261,10.599,9.5467,1.0523,15.6502,308.3268,0.0,4.1798,47
9.9609,0.1287,10.599,9.5467,1.0523,16.2121,308.5345,0.0,4.1826,47

I've attached a propeller to the motor and used a piece of soft plastic to hit the propeller.
I known the Nyquist frequency theorem saying that I can only detect frequencies below SAMPLE_RATE/2 Hz.
My questions are the following:

Why isn't the acceleration changing that much when I add the piece of plastic ?
Why is my FFT always showing 0.0 frequency ?
Where did I make a mistake in my code ?


Adding a portion of your data might help others in replicating your problem. "I'm using it's absolute value" <- This is not good though, acceleration signals should not always be positive. You are corrupting the signal when doing this and as MsSlater said, this leads to a DC offset which can be estimated as the mean of the signal. Before the taking the absolute of the signal, the mean should be around 0, and hence the FFT should produce nicer results. In addition, the swinging between positive to 0 and back to positive will be very fast and hence very high frequency components will shuw up.


I'm using it's absolute value (although it's not changing that much)

The former part is slightly worrying (abs(x) is a highly non-linear function) but the latter part means you're usually not oscillating around zero. So it's not that obvious in practice.
However, that description also means you have a very large constant component to your signal. That's typically called "DC", and will show up at 0 Hz. That makes sense: DC is the part of your signal which doesn't change at all.
Since you're interested in the non-DC parts, you should use np.fft.fft(data * np.blackman(n)))[1:n//2] and np.fft.fftfreq(n, d=1/n)[1:n//2].

Thanks for your answer. Now, frequency is set to 1.0.

I might have been a bit too terse. Did you also change the fft call itself?

Still no luck. The max amplitude is stuck on 1Hz. No matter what I do.
Here is a CSV export from my code: https://pastebin.com/bXQjyE4f
The fft_mean and fft_std are increasing according to the motor speed (as expected). max_amp is also increasing but the frequency is always stuck to 1.

@Manitoba: You really ought to be looking at the raw FFT values, not just a statistical summary of the absolute value.
